# Filling attributes with token

Tags: 7, ubercart, tokens

Has anyone ever come across the need to pass on values for product attributes in Ubercart through URLs? I've been trying to find something and the closest is https://www.drupal.org/project/uc_attribute_tokens, but this doesn't appear to be maintained well and the documentation is a little lacking. I'd appreciate any help in this.

Thanks! Matt